# what triggers itunes sign-in alert

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, itunes, storekit, skpaymenttransaction

I want to implement a new store feature in our app where there will be multiple non-consumables up for purchase. I went ahead and set up everything the way I want it and it actually works. Unfortunatly now every time the app is started or becomes active from the background there is an alert displayed asking to sign in to iTunes.

It's the same alert that would pop up if you download an app. It does not say anything about this being a sandbox environment. I tried to find the lines of code where I could possibly trigger this alert - I commented the code of this new store feature down to a bare graphical skeleton yet the altert remains. I tried to sign out and in from iTunes, restarted my iPod - nothing helps. If I reinstall our current app-version from the AppStore the alert vanishes.

So my question is: what exactly triggers this alert? Is there a way to debug this? Thanks in advance already.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like at some point maybe a transaction didn't get completed properly, and every time the app launches StoreKit is forwarding the incomplete transaction to your app to be handled. I've had similar issues before

I would guess that your device is signed in to an account which is different from the (presumably test) account (or not signed in at all) where the transaction in question took place, so it's prompting you (without providing any useful information) to sign in using that account to attempt to complete the transaction.

Comment: I checked for pending transactions and could not find any. 

As for the account. I am actually using only one account for all of the development. It's not set up as a sandbox account, but up till now worked very well with testFlight anyways. In the same app using the same account I have a subscription which works just fine.

Comment: Hmm that's strange then. Does your production app have the same id as the development version? If not, that would be my guess as to why it gets rid of the prompt, as then StoreKit has no app to forward the unfinished transaction to any more.

Comment: makes perfect sense, but it is the same app id

Comment: Hmm or production app is handling request differently than dev version. This stuff is so opaque it's really frustrating to debug.